# Which airlines provide on-board WiFi in Chinese airspace?

Tags: airlines, china, wifi

Many airlines provide on-board WiFi service, however the services are suspended when the plane is in Chinese airspace, even if the flight does not depart from or arrive to China.

Which airlines provide on-board WiFi that is still active in Chinese airspace?

Comment: None do, likely because the Great Firewall has no control over the satellite provider so China forbids it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least, Air China does ([source](http://skift.com/2013/07/04/air-china-start-free-wi-fi-service-on-flights-but-not-for-mobile-phones/)).

[China Eastern](http://europe.chinadaily.com.cn/business/2015-06/02/content_20883593.htm) has also started - for both domestic AND international flights.

A summary [article on this](http://technode.com/2013/07/04/finally-comes-the-in-flight-wi-fi-service-in-china/) notes that Hainan Air is also introducing it in China as well.